# R programming ignoring/removing NA values

Tags: r, delimiter, na

So I have data imported to r using data=read.delim("clipboard")

This is the last sections of the data....so I decided to use data2=na.omit(data,method="linear") which gave me this result...

But as you can see I have lost data from 290 to 293 ....for the 3rd and 4th column....pls help remove those NA values without losing data from the other columns...The data I have given you represents time and speed data...and what I'm trying to do is find the average speed every 100s etc...using a code pointed out to me earlier in my previous questions which is in this link...h

Comment: That's not possible; you should tell us what you expect instead of the NA. If you expect "empty", the only format that supports this is strings, so the whole columns would be converted to a string. Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: where did you get `method="linear"` from? I can't see that in the documentation anywhere. Not that it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the na values as they are but use na.rm in your subsequent manipulations; eg, `sum(df[,1], na.rm = TRUE)` where df is your data frame.

Comment: So would I enter it like this: data2=na.omit(data,na.rm=TRUE)??...if so...I still get the same output

Comment: No.  Get your data into R and accept that you have NA values, when you want to do something with the data, then begin to worry about it.  So, if you have your data in R, when you want to do something with it (my example was to sum a column, you may want to do something different) then worry about it.  In my example I used na.rm to work with the data.  Also, @Dieter has a point, if you tell us what you're hoping to do we may be able to give a better answer.

Comment: Hi Marco, the key point is what @DieterMenne has commented (hence all the upvotes on the comment).  What does it mean to you to "remove" the NAs?  What do you expect to see there instead?  --- What the question is really asking, in other words, is **why do you want to remove them?**.   Presumably, whatever answer to that, you will be able to address "down the line" in other calculations as user1945827 has pointed out.